# Prove that a linear map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$ that sends unit vectors to unit vectors is Unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

I believe the title contains all useful information for the problem. I tried to show that this map would have to be an isometry, but I can't seem to ensure that orthogonal vectors in the domain remain orthogonal in the image.

Comment: Such a linear map is norm-preserving and thus injective, and thus by rank-nullity, it is an isomorphism. By the polarization identity, norm-preserving and linear implies inner product-preserving. So, coupled with being an isomorphism, you have a unitary map. The key is the polarization identity (which in the real case is just a fancy way of saying $ab=\frac{(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2}{4}$, and in the complex case is essentially this with a few more $i$’s).

Comment: Thank you, I realized from your comment that it must be norm-preserving since any vector can just be scaled down to be a unit vector then scaled back after applying the linear map.

Comment: I would add that isometries preserve triangles so norm preserving implies it will also preserve orthogonality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$T$ preserves inner product iff $\|T\alpha \|=\|\alpha\|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626701/t-preserves-inner-product-iff-t-alpha-alpha) or this? [Confirmation of correctness in proof regarding norm preserving operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405751) or that? [relations between distance-preserving, norm-preserving, and inner product-preserving maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169991) or [other similar posts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=norm-preserving)